# Replace Infinity values in a PostgreSQL numeric[] array field

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in a [PG 14 database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html) having a column containing `Infinity` values in numeric[] arrays as follow:

```sql
SELECT id, factors_list FROM mytable ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2;

id | factors_list
---+-------------
1  | {Infinity,1,2.91825,2.2911174796669,1.58367915763394,1.96345397169765,1.41599564744287}
2  | {Infinity,1,1.0625,2.114,4.25,2.18021276595745}
```

The data type of this column is `ARRAY` (numeric[]) and the length of the array is variable (with some records being `NULL`):

```sql
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
table_name = 'mytable' AND column_name = 'factors_list';


   column_name  | data_type 
----------------+-----------
 factors_list   | ARRAY
```

In order to restore this database table into an older (<14) PG database, I need to replace all `Infinity` values by any valid number, let's say `99999999`.

How could I achieve that in an efficient way? (I have roughly 200'000 rows)

Comment: Why would you need to replace the `Infinity` values? Support for `Infinity` goes back until Postgres 8.2 (and possibly even earlier). What is this "older PG database" that doesn't support Infinity?

Comment: `"PostgreSQL 13.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit"` :

`ERROR:  cannot convert infinity to numeric
SQL state: 0A000`

Comment: Indeed `numeric` doesn't support infinity - but your column must be defined as `float[]` or `double precision[]`  - you didn't mention that you want to convert this to `numeric`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple update statement should do the job:

```sql
UPDATE mytable 
   SET factors_list = array_replace(factors_list, 'Infinity', 99999999)
 WHERE TRUE;
```

Comment: recommend to first copy some rows into a test table and update those, `SELECT * INTO test_table FROM columns LIMIT 1000`. UPDATEs always make me nervous.

Comment: @bfris: Then using transactions and no auto commit may help you... ;)

Comment: It's definitely not recommended to be nervous with databases.